# Ajax Request Results in form being submitted aswell

Tags: ajax, forms, submit

As the title states my Ajax call is actually causing the form to be submitted to its default action, why? I've never come across this before, all my other ajax calls have never done this.

```
function newAjax(t,u){ //t = type(post/get), u = url
    var resource = null;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
        resource = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        resource = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        resource.overrideMimeType('text/html');
    }
    resource.open(t,u,false);
    resource.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    return resource;
}

function send_newsletter(){
    formObj = document.getElementById("news_form");
    var inputs = formObj.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    var parameters = "";
    for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        parameters += inputs[i].name+"="+encodeURI(inputs[i].value);
        if(i != inputs.length-1){
            parameters += "&";
        }
    }
    var url = "whereitshouldbegoing.com";
    var ajax = newAjax("POST",url);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = ajaxResult;
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    ajax.send(parameters);
}
```

It all works fine upto the .send line, which is the bugger which is causing the form to submit aswell(I also have no idea if the ajax request actually gets off).

The send_newsletter function is called from an input type="image" element with onclick="send_newsletter()"

Please don't tell me to use jQuery or another library, as much as I would love to, we can't use any external librarys, corporate guidelines and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input of type "image" will [behave the same as a submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1). Use an anchor or button type input to trigger your method.

```
<input type="button" onclick="send_newsletter()" value="Send" />

<button onlclick="send_newsletter()">... </button>

<a href="#" onclick="send_newsletter(); return false;"><img src="... /></a>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link, never knew image inputs worked as submits. I'll just convert to an img with an onclick, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a submit button to call `send_newsletter`?

`onreadystatechange` callback function `'ajaxResult'` is not called because you're doing a synchronous call to the server:

```
resource.open(t,u,false);
```

if you want `ajaxResult` to be called change it to :

```
resource.open(t,u,true);
```

for now that's what I see. You have to provide more info like how do you call `send_newsletter`?

---

**EDIT**:(following author comment)

an `INPUT` of type `image` is a ***graphical* submit button**.